# This code adds the same "myRndmNos" array twice. but i want it to add the unsorted "myRndmNos" and the sorted "bubblesorted" array. How do i get it?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

when i try to add the two arrays that I generated from random numbers and the sorted, it just add the unsorted array twice. what am i missing?

```
        boolean sorted = false;
        int temp;
        while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < myRndmNos.length - 1; i++) {
            if (myRndmNos[i] > myRndmNos[i+1]) {
                temp = myRndmNos[i];
                myRndmNos[i] = myRndmNos[i+1];
                myRndmNos[i+1] = temp;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

> i think this part is wrong

```
    for (int j = 0; j < myRndmNos.length; j++){
        bubblesorted[j] = myRndmNos[j];
    }
    
    System.out.println("Sorted"); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bubblesorted));
    
    if(myRndmNos.length == bubblesorted.length) 
        { 
            for (int k = 0; k < myRndmNos.length; k++)
            {
                arraySum[k] = myRndmNos[k] + bubblesorted[k];
                
            }
            System.out.println("Element-wise added two arrays");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraySum));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Two arrays are not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing the sorting before assigning the value to the new bubblesorted array or after it ?
Looking at the code, It looks like you have sorted the array , and then assigning the same values to bubblesorted array. This results in addition of same element in the array.
I would suggest to create both the array first, and then go for the sorting and adding functionality.

Comment: oh. what if i copy the first unsorted array to a new array, so i can add the both new arrays. so there will altogether 4 arrays

Comment: Alltogether yes. But you would need to create the arrays before doing sorting..
Because you are first sorting the arrays and then assigning the same value to bubblesorted array. So you can figure out where the problem is.